# IP address is not allowed for this token on API CALL

Tags: linux, api, networking, postman, port

please bear with me, I am a newbie in integrating APIs and so I am encountering some issues that need help from experts. I am working on API that has only the server IP address whitelisted to access resources on it. However, I am working from my local PC in doing the integration. Now when I try accessing the API from the localhost, it tells me that my PC's IP address is not allowed for the token I am using. I have tried to do some google search on how to use the server's IP address from my PC and I have come across something called PORT FORWARDING. I have tried to figure out what it is but I am getting some difficulties setting it up on my PC. Could someone help me with any alternatives to making requests using my server's address from my PC? If not, I will appreciate it if someone could explain to me what port-forwarding is in layman's language and if possible through a reference. Thank you in advance. I am on Linux-mint

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make a request with your server's IP address, the request has to at least pass through your server. Setting up an temporary SSH "port forward" is the easiest way to do it. The following command opens an SSH session with your server machine, and for the duration of the session the ssh client will listen for connections on TCP port 8443 on your dev machine and the server will forward them to somewebsite.net:443.

```
ssh -L 8443:somewebsite.net:443 your.server.name
```

If you now send a request to `https://localhost:8443` from Postman, SSH will tunnel the request to your server. The server will communicate with somewebsite.net on your behalf, and the request will have your server's IP address.

See longer discussion of this feature for example at:

- https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example
- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-port-forwarding

This style of port forwarding is not without its problems though. You are using HTTPS, which includes protections against a "middle man" intercepting connections like this. You can get around this by disabling certificate verification. Another problem is that somewebsite.net may expect you to set the `Host` HTTP request  header to "somewebsite.net", and it will be set to "your.server.name" instead.

Comment: The command you show will cause connections to the server's port 8443 to be proxied through the client, which will result in denials.  For this case you want `-L` forwarding not `-R` and then the development code can connect to localhost:8443 on the development box and it will proxy through the server so that the remote website sees the server's IP.

Comment: Ah thanks, will fix, I must have remembered it wrong

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer @Joni. One more clarification though: What if I don't know the specific port where somewebsite.net is running? For example, I am accessing somewebsite.net/catalogue_services/set_user_data, What do we do with :443?

Comment: ```ssh -L 843:https://somewebsite.com root@146.61.79.52 
root@146.61.79.52's password: 
bind [0.0.3.75]:443: Cannot assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 443
Could not request local forwarding.
```

Comment: If the URL does not have a port number, the default port number is used. 443 is the default port number for HTTPS. Also, you have to use a number over 1024 for the *local* port. You would need super user privileges to use 843. So try `8443:somewebsite.com:443`